# how to take username using security:authentication tag in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring. I want send username of logged in user to my controller.
I tried following code which is not working...

```
<form:input path="bidderName" value="<security:authentication property=/"principal.username/"/>" />
```

at value field I want to take username of logged in user.
Please Help. Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to send it to your Spring Controller. You can actually access it directly from there.

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
```

It seems you're trying to pass the logged-in user from a JSP form back to your controller

Comment: Thank you!!  Yes, I was trying to send username from jsp to controller.

Comment: I'm glad that worked. If you wanna know more about Spring Security, I put some guides at http://krams915.blogspot.com/p/tutorials.html